# NS Listview inverted (bottom to top) and loadMoreItems when hits the top

Tags: listview, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

Usually, Listview scrolls from top to bottom. To load more item, we hit the last bottom item like this:

```
<ListView *ngIf="messages" [items]="messages" (loadMoreItems)="onLoadMoreItems()" [itemTemplateSelector]="templateSelector" separatorColor="transparent">
    <ng-template nsTemplateKey="receiver" let-item="item">
      // more codes
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template nsTemplateKey="owner" let-item="item">
      // more codes
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

I try to invert the scrolling direction (**from bottom to top**). Also as this is for a chat application, I try to call the *loadMoreItems* function when the user hits the last top item.

Is there anyone here who already did that? Or has an idea on how I could proceed?
Thanks

Comment: Have you found out the solution to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @ParthPatel I just answered with the trick I used :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This may not be the best way to achieve it but at least it works.
My answer is inspired by many other ones.
Let me know if you have a better/more native solution.*

I kept the *ListView* and I added a *ngAfterViewInit* with a private function (*scrollToIndex*)

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.scrollToIndex();
    }, 2000);
}

private scrollToIndex(): void {
    let yourStackLayoutInstance = this.listview.nativeElement;
    yourStackLayoutInstance.scrollToIndex(this.messages.length-1);
}
```

The logic behind is to populate your *ListView* and when it's done you can scroll to the last item.

Each time you add a last item you have to call this *scrollToIndex* function.